# Add field and value into an object by reflection

Tags: java, reflection

#### original code:

- import, hide some irrelevant company package

```
import cn.hutool.core.date.LocalDateTimeUtil;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod;
import org.apache.ibatis.executor.Executor;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.SqlCommandType;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Interceptor;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Intercepts;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Signature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
```

- code:

```
private static final int ACTION_CREATE_FLAG = 0;
private static final int ACTION_UPDATE_FLAG = 1;
private static final String FIELD_ZONE_CODE = "zoneCode";
private static final String FIELD_ZONE_NAME = "zoneName";
private static final String FIELD_CREATE_USER_ID = "createUserId";
private static final String FIELD_CREATE_USER_NAME = "createUserName";
private static final String FIELD_CREATE_TIME = "createTime";
private static final String FIELD_UPDATE_USER_ID = "updateUserId";
private static final String FIELD_UPDATE_USER_NAME = "updateUserName";
private static final String FIELD_UPDATE_TIME = "updateTime";

private Object procUserInfo(Object obj, int type) {
    OauthUserInfo authUser = GpJwtUtils.current();
    if (obj == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (authUser == null) {
        authUser = new OauthUserInfo();
        authUser.setUserId("system");
        authUser.setUserName("systemUser");
    }
    Field[] fields = ConvertUtils.getAllFields(obj);
    for (Field field : fields) {
        try {
            if (!FIELD_ZONE_CODE.equals(field.getName())
                && !FIELD_ZONE_NAME.equals(field.getName())
                && !FIELD_CREATE_USER_ID.equals(field.getName())
                && !FIELD_CREATE_USER_NAME.equals(field.getName())
                && !FIELD_CREATE_TIME.equals(field.getName())
                && !FIELD_UPDATE_USER_ID.equals(field.getName())
                && !FIELD_UPDATE_USER_NAME.equals(field.getName())
                && !FIELD_UPDATE_TIME.equals(field.getName())) {
                continue;
            }
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if ((type == ACTION_CREATE_FLAG && FIELD_CREATE_TIME.equals(field.getName()))) {
                if (LocalDateTime.class == field.getType()) {
                    field.set(obj, LocalDateTimeUtil.now());
                } else {
                    field.set(obj, new Date());
                }
            } else if (type == ACTION_UPDATE_FLAG && FIELD_UPDATE_TIME.equals(field.getName())) {
                if (LocalDateTime.class == field.getType()) {
                    field.set(obj, LocalDateTimeUtil.now());
                } else {
                    field.set(obj, new Date());
                }
            }
            if (field.get(obj) != null) {
                continue;
            }
            // zoneCode
            if (FIELD_ZONE_CODE.equals(field.getName())) {
                Object value = field.get(obj);
                String zoneCode = (String) ThreadContextHandler.get(CommonConstant.CONTEXT_ZONE_CODE);
                if (type == ACTION_CREATE_FLAG && value == null && zoneCode != null) {
                    field.set(obj, zoneCode);
                }
            }
            if (FIELD_ZONE_NAME.equals(field.getName())) {
                Object value = field.get(obj);
                String zoneName = (String) ThreadContextHandler.get(CommonConstant.CONTEXT_ZONE_NAME);
                if (type == ACTION_CREATE_FLAG && value == null && zoneName != null) {
                    field.set(obj, zoneName);
                }
            }
            // createUser
            if (type == ACTION_CREATE_FLAG && FIELD_CREATE_USER_ID.equals(field.getName())) {
                field.set(obj, authUser.getUserId());
            }
            if (type == ACTION_CREATE_FLAG && FIELD_CREATE_USER_NAME.equals(field.getName())) {
                field.set(obj, authUser.getUserName());
            }
            // updateUser
            if (FIELD_UPDATE_USER_ID.equals(field.getName())) {
                field.set(obj, authUser.getUserId());
            }
            if (FIELD_UPDATE_USER_NAME.equals(field.getName())) {
                field.set(obj, authUser.getUserName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("procUserInfo fail:", e);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

- method call:

```
MappedStatement ms = (MappedStatement) invocation.getArgs()[0];
int actionFlag = ms.getSqlCommandType() == SqlCommandType.INSERT ? ACTION_CREATE_FLAG : ACTION_UPDATE_FLAG;
procUserInfo(parameterObject, actionFlag);
```

#### my try:

```
private static final int ACTION_CREATE_FLAG = 0;
private static final int ACTION_UPDATE_FLAG = 1;
private static final String FIELD_CREATE_TIME = "createTime";
private static final String FIELD_UPDATE_TIME = "updateTime";
private static final LinkedList<String> ZONE_CODE_NAMES = (LinkedList<String>)
    Arrays.asList("zoneCode","zoneName");
private static final LinkedList<String> FIELD_CREATE_NAMES = (LinkedList<String>)
    Arrays.asList("createUserId", "createUserName", FIELD_CREATE_TIME);
private static final LinkedList<String> FIELD_UPDATE_NAMES = (LinkedList<String>)
    Arrays.asList("updateUserId", "updateUserName", FIELD_UPDATE_TIME);

/**
* add zone info and createUser or updateUser info into an object
*
* @param obj any database related obj
* @param type 0 createUser，1 updateUser
* @return obj with zone info and createUser or updateUser info
*/
private Object procUserInfo(Object obj, int type) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    if (type != ACTION_UPDATE_FLAG && type != ACTION_CREATE_FLAG) {
        return obj;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> fieldInfo:getFieldInfos(type,obj,getAuthUser()).entrySet()) {
        try {
            setField(obj,fieldInfo.getKey(),fieldInfo.getValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("procUserInfo fail", e);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
private OauthUserInfo getAuthUser(){
    OauthUserInfo authUser = GpJwtUtils.current();
    if (authUser == null) {
        authUser = new OauthUserInfo();
        authUser.setUserId("system");
        authUser.setUserName("systemUser");
    }
    return authUser;
}
private void setField(Object obj, String fieldName, Object value) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    if (value == null) {
        return;
    }
    Field field = obj.getClass().getField(fieldName);
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
    ReflectionUtils.setField(field,obj,value);
}
private Map<String,Object> getFieldInfos(int type,Object obj,OauthUserInfo authUser) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    LinkedList<String> fieldNames = ZONE_CODE_NAMES;
    fieldNames.addAll(type == ACTION_CREATE_FLAG ? FIELD_CREATE_NAMES : FIELD_UPDATE_NAMES);
    List<Object> values = getValues(obj,authUser);
    return IntStream.range(0, fieldNames.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(fieldNames::get, values::get));
}
private LinkedList<Object> getValues(Object obj,OauthUserInfo authUser) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    LinkedList<Object> result = new LinkedList<>();
    result.add(ThreadContextHandler.get(CommonConstant.CONTEXT_ZONE_CODE));
    result.add(ThreadContextHandler.get(CommonConstant.CONTEXT_ZONE_NAME));
    result.add(authUser.getUserId());
    result.add(authUser.getUserName());
    result.add(LocalDateTime.class == obj.getClass().getField(FIELD_CREATE_TIME).getType() ?
        LocalDateTimeUtil.now() : new Date());
    result.add(LocalDateTime.class == obj.getClass().getField(FIELD_UPDATE_TIME).getType() ?
        LocalDateTimeUtil.now() : new Date());
    return result;
}
```

#### description:

1. I know the method name is not the best name, but I didn't find a better name now.
2. Control a method by `int type` maybe a `code smell`, but I didn't find a better solution either.
3. Declare a static variable combine with enum and string maybe a bad practice, such as `FIELD_CREATE_NAMES`, any better solution?

Comment: this really really needs some context so ppl are even able to look at this code:
- this **seems** to be somehow related to OAuth and JWT, but it's nowhere explained how;
- there's a lot of constants defined with **zero** explanation (javadocs) what's their meaning and where they should be used;
- the title of the post seems to correspond to a small helper method `setField()`: what's the purpose of all the other code then?;
- you've omitted all imports so, guessing the context is even harder: please bring 'em back ;-)

Comment: @morgwai ok I'll edit it to add more details, but OAuth really has no relation with it in this situation, it just a method get a userid and username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's too bad that the review context omits `import` statements.
They would have helped with looking up relevant documentation.

EDIT: Ok, I see those recently added Apache Ibatis imports, thank you.

## length

This method is entirely too long.
Fortunately, I see that below there's a revision which breaks out helpers, good.

## javadoc

This is super vague:

```
private Object procUserInfo(Object obj, int type) {
```

No idea what that object is all about, so I will just keep reading.
Maybe it is a "user info" object?

The `type` looks like it wants to be an `Enum`.

I *guess* we have an abbreviation for the verb "process", here?
But that's a pretty vague verb, so I don't know what
[promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
this method makes to its caller.
Spell it out, if I guessed correctly.
Maybe use a verb like "alter"?
Maybe ditch the `type` parameter,
and turn this into a pair of methods,
so an engineer can call

- createUserInfo(), or
- updateUserInfo()

Most importantly, if a three-word identifier cannot communicate
to the reader what this function does, then offer a one-sentence
/** javadoc */ explanation of what it does.
What's the post-condition?
How could I tell that the right thing happened, after calling it?

Oh good, I see that such a sentence has been added in the revised version.

## defer work

```
    OauthUserInfo authUser = GpJwtUtils.current();
```

In the case that `obj` is null, there's no need to make this call.
So just defer it until after that test.

Making someone the systemUser in the case that the `.current()` call failed
seems an odd default.
We don't want to make it harder to become systemUser?

## skip unknown field

Testing for unknown field name seems tediously long.
Maybe throw those known names into a HashSet, and test for membership?
Couldn't an Enum accomplish the same thing for us?

Consider turning some `if`s into a `switch` statement.

It's not clear why we need the INSERT / UPDATE `type` flag,
nor why it's OK for caller to specify mismatched `type` and name
and then we just silently ignore it.
Maybe we don't need that `type` parameter at all?
The field name seems to already specify what the caller intended.

## re-throw

At the end we log any exception that happened and then swallow it,
so caller believes we succeeded.
This seems Bad.
Prefer to log it and re-throw it, perhaps first wrapping it in a RuntimeException
if that makes the signatures more convenient.

---

Moving on to the revised version.

## javadoc

This is an improvement over nothing, but it's still not great.

```
/**
* add zone info and createUser or updateUser info into an object
*
* @param obj any database related obj
* @param type 0 createUser，1 updateUser
* @return obj with zone info and createUser or updateUser info
*/
```

Let's start with that "any database related obj" description,
which makes it clear that we chose the wrong identifier.
It isn't *any old* object `obj`.
It's a *database* object `dbObj`.

I still wish you'd given me a hint about some representative
class to which it might belong.
The review context just offers `parameterObject`,
which doesn't bring me any closer to enlightenment.
Offering [unit tests](https://junit.org/junit5)
would have been helpful -- they have instructional value.

When I try to parse the sentence,
"add zone info and createUser or updateUser info into [a database] object,"
I get a *little* closer to understanding the promise made,
better than "process user info," but I'm still left wanting more detail,
perhaps from a second sentence.
I at least now know the verb "process" implies the side effect
of either creating or updating some user info.

## helpers

Breaking out four helper methods,
starting with `getAuthUser`,
is a big win, thank you.

I appreciate that the contract is "getAuthUser shall never return null",
which simplifies logic up in the caller.
We validate pre-conditions,
then loop through some reads and writes,
very straightforward.

After logging an error we should re-throw,
rather than swallow the exception.

## fatal error

In `setField` it appears it may be better
to throw fatal RuntimeException,
rather than silently ignore a `null` input
which caller should never have sent us in the first place.

Writing lots of code involves writing some bugs.
When we write bugs we prefer that they be **shallow** bugs.
It should be easy to pin the blame on where the bug started,
and fix it there, rather than debugging through a call stack
in search of the root cause.